# How can I detect if gearman is working?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gearman

I installed [gearman](http://gearman.org/) and configured jenkins to connect to it. I tested that jenkins can connect to gearman. Now, I am creating another application to detect that gearman is still up and running. Is it possible to do that? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to gearman through a regular tcp connection on port 4730. After connecting you can issue the command `status` to get a list of registered functions, queue status and number of assigned workers, or `workers` to see a list of clients. Some libraries abstract away this (look for something mentioning `Gearman Admin`) depending on your language and library of choice.

The complete Admin protocol (which isn't much larger, really) can be seen on the protocol page at the Gearman homepage.